# How to update content of JSON file in gitlab using gitlab-ci.yml?

Tags: json, docker, gitlab, yaml, gitlab-ci

I'm building docker image for specific version of browser & pushing it to AWS ecr.
After running docker push command, I wanted to update `status = deployed` in JSON file in gitlab.
After push command, the command for changing status is getting skipped by gitlab. The command is working on my local machine but skipped in gitlab

Below is the script inside gitlab-ci.yml file

```
publish-firefox:
  image: 
    name: amazon/aws-cli:2.2.38
    entrypoint: [""]
  services:
    - docker:dind
  before_script:
    - amazon-linux-extras install -y docker
    - aws --version
    - docker --version
    - yum install jq -y
  script:
    - cd /builds/firefox-dockerfile
    - aws ecr get-login-password | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin $DOCKER_REGISTRY_DEV       
    - > 
       jq -c '.[]' firefox-versions.json | while read i; do
          STATUS=$(echo $i | jq -r .STATUS)
          FIREFOX_VERSION=$(echo $i | jq -r .FIREFOX_VERSION)
          GECKODRIVER_VERSION=$(echo $i | jq -r .GECKODRIVER_VERSION)
          if [[ "$STATUS" != "deployed" ]]
          then
              docker build -t $DOCKER_REGISTRY_DEV/$APP_NAME:"$FIREFOX_VERSION" --build-arg FIREFOX_VERSION="$FIREFOX_VERSION" --build-arg GECKODRIVER_VERSION="$GECKODRIVER_VERSION" .
              docker push $DOCKER_REGISTRY_DEV/$APP_NAME:"$FIREFOX_VERSION"
              tmp=$(mktemp)
              cat firefox-versions.json | jq --arg a "$STATUS" '.[].STATUS = "deployed"' firefox-versions.json >"$tmp" && mv "$tmp" firefox-versions.json
          else
              if [[ "$STATUS" = "deployed" ]]; then
                  echo 'Firefox-'"$FIREFOX_VERSION"' is already created and pushed to ECR'
              fi
          fi
      done
```

JSON file = firefox-versions.json

```
[
    {
        "FIREFOX_VERSION": "79.0b9",
        "GECKODRIVER_VERSION": "0.29.1",
        "STATUS": "deployed"
    },
    {
        "FIREFOX_VERSION": "88.0b8",
        "GECKODRIVER_VERSION": "0.29.1",
        "STATUS": ""
    }
]
```

can anyone help me with this?

Comment: You may need to present your gitlab pipeline configuration. Is jq installed on the CI image?

Comment: yes it's installed

Comment: Your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file (or the snippet you showed) is invalid. The `->` in your script section is causing the issue. I'm not sure if that's supposed to be part of the command or not, but commands to be run in the script (or before_script and after_script) section(s) need to start with a `-`. The `script` section is just an array of commands, and in yml an array is marked with `-`'s. Since that command doesn't have a `-`, it's not included as part of the commands array, and isn't executed.

Comment: As I mentioned, till `docker push $DOCKER_REGISTRY_DEV/$APP_NAME:"$FIREFOX_VERSION"` my code is working. After that its skipping `cat firefox-versions.json | jq --arg a "$STATUS" '.[].STATUS = "deployed"' firefox-versions.json >"$tmp" && mv "$tmp" firefox-versions.json` this command only. So, script section is not an issue over thr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved:
after the `cat firefox-versions.json | jq --arg a "$STATUS" '.[].STATUS = "deployed"' firefox-versions.json >"$tmp" && mv "$tmp" firefox-versions.json` command I've added git token and its commands to commit and push json file to GitLab